# How to create a new string with the prefix of 2 given strings?

Tags: string, python-3.x

gets the length of the common prefix of two words i.e-the common prefix of "global" and "glossary" is "glo"(length 3)

```
a= input("Enter string: ")
b= input("Enter string: ")
count=0
c=a.startswith(b)
while count<=c:
    if c:
        count=count+1
print(count)
```

what im not sure is how to get the length of the common prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
def pre(s1, s2):
    if any(bool(s.strip())==False for s in (s1, s2)):
        return 0

    for i, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        if c1!=c2:
            return i

    return i+1
```

Testing:

```
>>> pre("global", "glossary")
3
>>> pre("global", "global")
6
>>> pre("global", "")
0
```

Comment: You could also use `for i, (t1, t2) in ...` and `if t1 != t2`

Answer (score 0):

You can "cheat" (as in - it's not the way it's *meant* to be used, but oh well) and use `os.path.commonprefix` which does a char by char comparison on all elements passed, eg:

```
from os.path import commonprefix

a = 'global'
b = 'glossary'
length = len(commonprefix([a, b]))
# 3
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can avoid using commonprefix  and like in the answer above the use of enumerate and use more simpler methods?

Comment: @CarlyleBritto depends what you think is *simple*... you could one-liner Pyson's answer, but that won't benefit you anything